# How to do Future Scala?

Tags: scala

I don't understand why Future doesn't work? Can someone help me? I got this code from official scala website. It's doesn't compile error Future.type doesn't take parameters

```
import scala.concurrent.Future
import java.lang.Thread.sleep

object Future extends App {

  def getStockPrice(stockSymbol: String): Future[Double] = Future {
    val r = scala.util.Random
    val randomSleepTime = r.nextInt(3000)
    val randomPrice = r.nextDouble * 1000
    sleep(randomSleepTime)
    randomPrice
  }

}
```

Comment: What does _"doesn't work"_ mean? Does it not compile? Does it fail with a runtime exception? does it give you an unexpected result? - Note that your code does nothing btw.

Comment: Doesn't compile
'Future.type' doesn't take parameters

Comment: What is the URL of the page where you got this code from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the object name from `Future` to something else. You also need an implicit `ExecutionContext` available. Following will work.

```
import scala.concurrent.Future
import java.lang.Thread.sleep
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

object FutureApp extends App {

  def getStockPrice(stockSymbol: String): Future[Double] = Future {
    val r = scala.util.Random
    val randomSleepTime = r.nextInt(3000)
    val randomPrice = r.nextDouble * 1000
    sleep(randomSleepTime)
    randomPrice
  }

}
```